# Selecting objects by name starting with

Tags: python

I have many objects in the scene as they have been duplicated. pad, pad.001, pad.002 etc etc.
I require a python code to select all of them by name.. name starting with 'pad'
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following snippet iterates through the objects in the scene and checks if their name matches a prefix. If it does it's added to the list.

```
objs = [obj for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects if obj.name.startswith("pad")]
```

If you want to select them, as in selecting them in the scene, then you can do the following for 2.7x:

```
for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if obj.name.startswith("pad"):
        obj.select=True
```

For 2.8:

```
for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if obj.name.startswith("pad"):
        obj.select_set(True)
```

You could also use:

```
bpy.ops.object.select_pattern(pattern="pad*")
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 3, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Object' object has no attribute 'select'

Comment: Is this for 2.8, I've tried the script. it will not select the objects.

Comment: @MichaelTeiniker updated the answer for 2.8.

Comment: works, how would I make the active objects selected? I have tried this, no luck. activeObject = bpy.context.active_object

Comment: @MichaelTeiniker I'm not sure what you mean. Active objects are already selected.

Comment: before using the script another object was selected, so I use bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT') to deselect all objects first, then use the script. This will select all "pad" objects and highlight them, yet the previous object name is still displayed top left. I'm trying to join all "pad". Message appears "Active object is not selected mesh"

Comment: @MichaelTeiniker I see, that's because you have selected objects but not an active one. You can make of the objects active by using `bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj` were `obj` needs to be one of the objects from `bpy.context.scene.objects`.